# How to add (energy) constraint when using NDSolve to Equation of Motion

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics

To simplify my problem, I will try and solve the Equation of Motion for a particle in a 1D Harmonic Potential.

```
energy[x_, p_, m_, ω_] := p^2/(2 m) + (m ω^2)/2 x^2
```

I can define the following function to use NDSolve to solve for the Equation of Motion:

```
sol[x0_, p0_, m_, ω_, time_] := NDSolve[
  {
   x'[t] == p[t]/m,
   p'[t] == -m ω^2 x[t],
   x[0] == x0,
   p[0] == p0
  },
  {x[t], p[t]},
  {t, 0, time},
  MaxSteps -> ∞
]
```

I can run the function `sol`, however, if I plot how the energy changes in time:

```
    trajectory = sol[2, 1, 1, 1, 1000];

    Plot[
      Evaluate[
        energy[x[t], p[t], 1, 1] /. trajectory
      ],
      {t, 0, 1000}
    ]
```

[image]

I understand in this case, the energy changes very slowly with time. However, I would still like to fix the energy. Naively, the first thing I tried was:

```
    solConstraint1[x0_, p0_, m_, ω_, time_] := NDSolve[
      {
       x'[t] == p[t]/m,
       p'[t] == -m ω^2 x[t],
       energy[x[t], p[t], m, ω] == energy[x0, p0, m, ω],
       x[0] == x0,
       p[0] == p0
      },
      {x[t], p[t]},
      {t, 0, time},
      MaxSteps -> ∞
    ]
```

`solConstraint1` doesn't run at all, then I came across the following [Model Constrained Systems as DAEs](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/model-constrained-systems-as-daes.html)

```
    solConstraint2[x0_, p0_, m_, ω_, time_] := NDSolve[
      {
       x'[t] == p[t]/m,
       p'[t] == -m ω^2 x[t],
       energy[x[t], p[t], m, ω] == energy[x0, p0, m, ω],
       x[0] == x0,
       p[0] == p0
      },
      {x[t], p[t]},
      {t, 0, time},
      Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}
    ]
```

`solConstraint2` doesn't run as well. Is there something I am doing wrongly? How do I add an energy constraint to the equation of motion for `NDSolve`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know offhand what is a good way to recast as a DAE. One way to enforce the algebraic constraint, without getting an overdetermined (albeit consistent) system, is to use the projection method. I cribbed some of the submethod settings from advanced documentation in tutorial/NDSolveProjection.

```
sol2[x0_, p0_, m_, ω_, time_] := 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == p[t]/m, p'[t] == -m ω^2 x[t], x[0] == x0, 
   p[0] == p0}, {x[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, time}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
  Method -> {"Projection", 
    Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, "PositionVariables" -> {x[t]}}, 
    "Invariants" -> energy[x[t], p[t], m, ω]}, PrecisionGoal -> 12]
```

This seems to remove that drift off the constraint manifold and also to keep fluctiations to around 10^(-9). Could perhaps do better with more tuning of the various options and suboptions.

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html#1966826857),

```
solConstraint2[x0_, p0_, m_, ω_, time_] := 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == p[t]/m, p'[t] == -m ω^2 x[t], x[0] == x0, p[0] == p0},
  {x, p}, {t, 0, time}, 
  Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> energy[x[t], p[t], m, ω]}}]
```

This keeps the energy to within about 0.12 of its starting value.  Not great, but it does not drift.

Note:  Using the option `WorkingPrecision -> 50` on the original `sol` also reigns in the drift and keeps it around `6 * 10^-10`.

Comment: This looks like an appropriate time to use a symplectic method.

Comment: @J.M. Daniel beat me to it.